# Add files to TeamCity artifact zip

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

We are using TeamCity as CI and we are struggling with the final build step: We pull a dependency from another build step (a zip) and want to add a few extra files. Do we really need to extract the zip (quite large file), copy the files over there and zip it again? Is there support or a plugin to add files to existing zip files?

Comment: when you say you are pulling a dependency (zip) from another build step, how is this zip getting generated in the first place?

Comment: Using TeamCity's built-in artifact packaging. ./BuildOutput/**=>MyArtifact.zip

Comment: @JelleVergeer. Where can I find the built-in artifact packaging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeamCity itself does not support this and I haven't seen any related plugins, however, if you really need to wait until the final step to add the extra files (maybe you are doing some kind of file generation at this point), then I would recommend using something like 7Zip.

you can **update** existing zip files (assuming they are not "solid" archives") with a very simple command:

```
7za.exe u targetZip.zip file.ext
```

this will add "file.ext" to the zip file "targetZip.zip" without decompressing and re-compressing the archive.

you can find 7Zip here: http://www.7-zip.org/

Comment: Thanks! I had a feeling this would require some custom script build step / plugin. Unfortunately, including those files in an earlier step is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

It would be much better to include those files at the previous step, which lists which files should be included to the final artifact. Rather than trying to modify the already generated artifact. So basically all you need is to add an additional build step that will simply copy those other files to the output folder from which you are producing your final artifact.

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't an option. The artifact is pulled as a dependency from another project.